# Export C# Console Application as an Android .apk File

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, console-application

Is there a way to build a C# Console application as an APK file and export it on an Android device? I have a Console application that starts different types of applications at runtime and one of those is an Android Application using Xamarin Forms.

I thought that if I managed to somehow deploy this Console Application to my Android device, then I could start it by using Intents.

Comment: Do you want to make this console application to be an android app? I think you could just copy the code to an activity or service.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'd like to do. Do you know any such activities or services? The only thing I've found so far that could achieve this is mkbundle from mono.